# how to override delegate methods in category?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, overriding, uialertview, objective-c-category

I have created category for `UIAlertView` and overridden the delegate method `willPresentAlertView` but my method in the category not getting fired.

**sample code :**

```
@interface UIAlertView (CustomAlert)
@end

@implementation UIAlertView (CustomAlert)
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView1
{

    for (UIView *sub in [alertView1 subviews])
    {
        if([sub class] == [UIImageView class])
        {
            ((UIImageView *)sub).image=nil;
            ((UIImageView *)sub).backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
    }

    [alertView1.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [alertView1.layer setCornerRadius:0];
    [alertView1.layer setBorderWidth:2];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do you want it in a category? What is the purpose?

Comment: delegate methods are run from delegate object, source object hav to only launch the method which will be executed in a way that delegate object wants it. If you want additional functionality, you can write it in category or subclass. If you want to implement delegate methods, you can do it in delegate object's class.

Comment: Have you set the alert view as its own delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intent is providing a default implementation for `willPresentAlertView` delegate method, then your approach (defining `willPresentAlertView` in a `UIAlertView` category) is correct. You only need to pass the alert itself as a delegate so that the method is called:

```
 UIAlertView* alert = ...
 alert.delegate = alert;
```

If you do not do that, your delegate method will not be called.

On the other hand, I doubt that defining a default implementation like that is really of great use, since in principle each alert would need its own specific delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
@interface MONBlackStyle : NSObject // << new class, not category
+ (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView1;
@end

@interface MONOrangeStyle : NSObject // << new class, not category
+ (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView1;
@end
```

no category required. of course, the alert parameter is redundant when you use that category on `UIAlertView` and of course the definitions of the messages above could call some other category method if access is the issue. also note that in this exact example, the delegate would be set as such: `alert.delegate = [MONOrangeStyle class];` that's one step in the right direction but more steps could be taken. good luck.